# Why is reflexivity enough in this HoTT formulation of quotient types?

Tags: homotopy-type-theory

In [this formulation of quotient types in cubical type theory](https://gist.github.com/gergoerdi/4ff359b58657d816d5876b8b15c6640a) I was able to implement an eliminator and use that to implement basically curried function application. However, in all this, the only requirement on the factoring relation is that it is reflexive.

I find this surprising. I would have expected transitivity and symmetry to also be needed somewhere along the way. Is there an intuitive explanation for why reflexivity is enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Quot` construction is a set-truncated quotient by an *arbitrary* relation $R$ since you never use the reflexivity assumption in the construction. That is, you don't even need the reflexivity of $R$ to perform the quotient and derive its basic properties.

As the HoTT book explains in Section 6.10, it is perfectly possible to make set-truncated quotients by an arbitrary relation because reflexivity, transitivity and symmetry are taken care of by the paths themselves (because there are identity paths, paths can be reversed, and composed). That is, the quotient $A/R$ is equivalent to the quotient $A/\overline{R}$ where $\overline{R}$ is the equivalence relation generated by $R$.

There is one property that you will *not* get, namely that (using the notations from your file) $(x : A) \to (y : A) \to \mathsf{point}\;x = \mathsf{point}\;y \to R\;x\;y$. For that you need the fact that $R$ is a proposition and an equivalence relation.

Comment: No wait, I actually am using the reflexivity of the underlying relation, namely, when I am turning a pair of `quot {x} {y} eq i` and a `point a` into a `quot (eq , (? : a ≈ a)) i`.

Comment: Hmm, can't do this right now, the HoTT book Section 6.10 should state an appropriate elimination principle, please compare that with the one you've stated.

Comment: For representation-invariance, in my eliminator I ask for `∀ {x y} (eq : x ∼ y)→ PathP (λ i → P (quot {x = x} {y = y} eq i)) (point* x) (point* y))`, I can't imagine what else I would possibly require.

Comment: Here is the [HoTT-Agda formulation of set-quotients](https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT-Agda/blob/master/core/lib/types/SetQuotient.agda#L20). I don't know enough of Agda do decipher what you're doing (what is `PathP`, I see it's something cubical, but what?), I hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry for being dense here, but in your comment starting with "No wait ..." which code lines are you referring to, precisely?

Comment: Right, sorry for being vague in my previous comment; the comment box's small size unconsciously forced me to be be  brief. The usages of the reflexivity of the underlying relation that I have trouble removing are the ones in `fromPair`; line 47 in the source linked in my question is the first such occurrence that have no obvious replacement once I remove `~-refl` from the context.

Comment: `PathP` here is the `PathOver` construction from the library you linked (a path with differently-typed endpoints, where there is a path between the endpoint types), only cubically.

Comment: Yes, I see. You're defining there a map $A_1/R_1 \to A_2/R_2 \to (A_1 \times A_2)/(R_1 \times R_2)$. That in itself has nothing to do with the definition of quotients., but rahter with the interaction between quotients and products. I think it's a bit more sophisticated than what you did. Let me think.